# Atlassian.Net SDK get all projects and sprints

Tags: c#, jira-rest-api, jira-agile, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am using Atlassian .net SDK from NuGet gallery.
I am able to retrieve all the issues with below code:

```
    var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient("https://xxxx.atlassian.net", "user name", "pwd");

    var jiraIssues = from i in jira.Issues.Queryable

                 orderby i.Created
                 select i;

    foreach (var issue in jiraIssues)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(issue.Key.Value + " -- " + issue.Summary);
    }
```

But I am not able to get all the Projects, Sprints etc. Can anybody help me on this ?

Comment: No, I could not find anything on Atlassian docs, and anyone does not know something regarding this topic. :)

Answer (score 0):

This one is for projects.

```
var projects = await jira.Projects.GetProjectsAsync();
```